# ASP.NET 5, DNX & Kestrel: Not hitting breakpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, kestrel-http-server

Breakpoints are not being hit when debugging our DNX projects referenced in a ASP.NET 5 API project hosted with Kestrel (all in the same solution and in the src folder).  Debugging with IIS Express works fine.

**What troubleshooting steps can be taken to solve this problem?**

No binaries or PDBs are created with DNX projects when debugging, so I am very unsure as to where to start.

**project.json commands:**

```
"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},
```

**Project properties:**

[image: Project properties]

**Note:** Using the RC1 `1.0.0-rc1-final` libraries in all projects.

### **EDIT:**

- Breakpoints in the Startup.cs project are hit just fine, but not in other projects.
- I have double checked and reinstalled the `1.0.0-rc1-update1` DNX runtime. I have uninstalled all other runtimes.
- I have confirmed that PATH reflects the DNX runtime correctly.
- I have deleted all `project.lock.json` files and DNU restored.
- The actual breakpoint pin is red and doesn't indicate that there should be any problem.
- global.json is using the correct runtime:

  ```
  {
    "projects": [ "src", "test", "." ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
  }
  ```

### **EDIT 2:**

In the Modules window, I can see that the projects' symbols aren't loading:

[image: Modules]

How can I fix this?

### **EDIT 3:**

I found that this problem **only occurs when running multiple startup projects at the same time**. When running a single project, debugging works just fine in all projects within the solution.

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this and why it is happening.

Comment: Have you tried running your application via console command (dnx web)? Try to start your app in that way and then attach to process called dnx

Comment: @MarcinZablocki: Yes, the breakpoint isn't hit either.

Comment: But is the breakpoint colored red (indicates that it will be hit) ?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki: Yes, it is red. I have updated the question with other things I have checked/done.

Comment: See the modules and check if symbols are loaded. PDBs and DLLs are not created since the code is compiled on the fly and assemblies along with PDBs are loaded from streams from memory instead of files. As a last resort publish your app using Debug configuration which I think would create dlls and pdbs then you can run it using `dnx --debug web` which will allow you to attach to the process...

Comment: @Pawel: The symbol state for these projects is "Cannot find or open the PDB file." See my second EDIT in the question.

Comment: What code you want to debug? You hid the names of dlls but as you can see they are marked as not user code and they are not built dynamically. Are you trying to debug Kestrel itself and the rest of aspnet? If this is the case you may want to add a project to your global.json file

Comment: These are dnx projects in the solution; class libraries used by the web project essentially. They are user code.

Comment: * Check if there is a `artifacts` directory somewhere in the directory structure and remove it.

* try to start from scratch and create two new projects with one referencing the other and check if you can debug correctly - this way you can verify if there is something wrong with your projects or the whole environment.

Comment: Have the exact same issue using Visual Studio 2015 - Update 1. Tried everything that has been suggested here to no avail.

Comment: This problem only occurs when running multiple startup projects.  See my edit.

Comment: Removing "artifacts" directory and restarting helped (Visual Studio 2015 Update 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filed this issue on the [aspnet/Tooling](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling) GitHub repository. Consensus is that this is a bug and will only be fixed with the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 release.

An interim solution is to use a separate instance of VS for each process.

See issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/367#issuecomment-171386435).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue spend whole day and still no avail. I re-created project however it is strange enough that debug hit controller class for MVC Core in first debug after project created but not after that only main class i.e. startup.cs is hit breaking point everytime